# GCC 4.5.0..linking error during compilation?

Tags: g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference, libstdc++

Well I've recently come out of the dark ages and upgraded my GCC from **3.4.4** to **4.5.0** with Cygwin (I use Netbeans 6.8 on Windows for future reference). I tried testing the new compiler by attempting to run a simple program through it. The run failed however, citing that NetBeans "cannot find -lstdc++".

Interesting.

I look in ...

> C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.0

...where **libstdc++.a**, **libstdc++.dll.a**, **libstdc++.la**, **libsupc++.a**, and **libsupc++.la** are supposed to be (they're in that spot in the 3.4.4 folder), and they're not there. I also notice something else: there's a 4.3.4 folder in...

> C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin

which contains these exact files! Good. So I copy them in to the 4.5.0 folder and try to run the program again. This time i'm getting two other errors:

> build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/extract_fail_operations.o:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:1435: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::_List_node_base*)'

and:

> build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/extract_fail_operations.o:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:1451: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'

At this point I figured that I was way over my head and decided to come for help before copying and pasting any more files. If anyone could tell me how to get this working, i'd be really appreciative.

(If any solutions involve the command line, please be warned that i'm not well versed in it... you may have to provide extra details that you wouldn't need to to other SO users!)

**EDIT:** The PATH variables are as follows:

> C:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Program Files\CVSNT\;C:\cygwin\bin

And yes, the Cygwin installed is the latest from the site.

Comment: My guess is that for some reason your new install just isn't in your path.  Right click on my computer, pull up properties and under advanced there should be a list of environment vara.  Update your post with them.    Also, you did get your newer package from the cygwin site, right?

Comment: Ok. the original post was updated with your requests fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install version 4.5.0 of libstdc++6-devel.

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same problem after upgrading gcc packages using Cygwin's setup.exe.